How to implement latest MAUI Service Release
I have a MAUI App that uses Blazor Hybrid, and there is a bug that causes it to display a blank page in iOS 18 beta.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/23390
This bug is fixed and released in the latest MAUI service release https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases/tag/8.0.80
But I can't work out how to get that into my App. is there a way? Or do I need to wait for the next release of the dotnet 8 SDK?

You can now install the latest .NET MAUI releases through NuGet.
If you don't have an entry already in your csproj, add this:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.80" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

If you do have this already, just update the Version value.
If you don't use Blazor Hybrid you don't need the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui one and hopefully you shouldn't need the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility either so mix and match as needed.
For more information see this issue.
